# How do I find the location of the Cie'th Stone missions?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

So, I've been looking around for the Cie'th Stone missions, and I've managed to do the first 3. Problem is, I'm looking for the 4th, and I'm just not finding it. Is there an easier way to find them besides just wandering around?

Comment: Not that I know off.. what I did was riding a Chocobo this way wandering around became much faster and more fun. Hmm.. actually, when you see pack of monsters in the horizon, it usually means there's a stone nearby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than [using a guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/final-fantasy-xiii-cieth-stone-missions-guide/), you basically need to wander around, though all the mission stones are marked on the map, so you don't have to wander too much.

Keep in mind that a number of the missions are not in the main Gran Pulse area, which includes mission 4 - it is in Yaschas Massif.

Comment: You don't need to do them in order, either.